# php redirect check

Tags: php, redirect

Is there anyway to determine if a page has come from a php redirect?

I have a session saved of the last time the page was refreshed, but i dont want it to set if the page has come from an instantly referred one.

To give some idea of what i'm doing, i have this code on my site to stop users refreshing more than once per second:

```
$now = time();
if ($_SESSION['click'] > ($now-1)) { 
   exit("Woah, you're clicking too fast!") ; 
   }
$_SESSION['click'] = $now;
```

However, I don't want the click session to set if the page has from from a php redirect, or a form post, etc. Any solutions?

Answer (score 1):

How about using referer?

```
if( $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] == "http://mydomain.com/formmail.php" )
```